# How to store list of dictionaries returned in Redis using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am writing a NodeJS app that does a get request to a third party api.  This api returns a list of dictionaries.  I would like to take this result, and store it in my redis client.  How do I do that?

The results object looks like this -

```
[{"foo":123, "bar":456}, {"foo":789, "bar":012}]
```

Comment: It's difficult to give much of an answer without knowing how to would like to retrieve the data out of redis, because that will dictate how you enter it into redis.  How would you like to retrieve the data?

Comment: @generalhenry So once redis has the above list of dictionaries into Redis, I would do a lpop mylist to get the values.  This will return an element of type dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't need to query elements from the dicts so it should be fine just storing them as json strings in a redis list.  When you bulk add to the list you can stringify them, just make sure to use some form of pipe-lining so you're not making unneeded api calls. Then you can simply parse the json string dicts when you need them. ex:

```
function setList (list, callback) {
  const pipeline = redis.pipeline();
  for (const dict of list) {
    pipeline.rpush('myList', JSON.stringify(dict));
  }
  pipeline.exec(callback);
}

function popList (callback) {
  redis.lpop('mylist', function (error, data) {
    if (error) { return callback(error) }
    callback(null, JSON.parse(data));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it simple assuming your data as list or list as string,

```
      let redis = require("redis"),
      publisher = redis.createClient(option.redisPort, option.redisHost); 
      publisher.publish("id", DATA);  // here we publish the data.
```

Are you looking for something like this?